Jewish Kids Books That Don't Treat Midrash as Mikra?
My wife and I are struggling to find Jewish books for our kids that don't distinguish between mikra and midrash. I open up a Jewish book for kids and every biblical story has more midrash than mikra in it. I've gotten a JPS Childrens Bible which is great for Mikra, but it has nothing from the oral law. Are there any childrens books that distinguish these two sources of our history?

Get the JPS Children's Bible and the Little Midrash Says and voila.

What you seek seems by definition not a children's work, but something more advanced.

@DoubleAA Doesn't the Mishnah/Gemara to say to teach Mikra first, then after its complete Mishnah, and that after that Gemara? Are you saying that Mikra is too advanced for children?

@Aaron That doesn't mean mikra with no commentary.

@Aaron Huh? I didn't say Miqra is too advanced for children. Plenty of straight translations of Miqra exist

@DoubleAA you're saying what's harder for kids is for a single book to present both miqra and midrash as such, and ask them to keep them straight. Yeah. In middle school music class, we learned about The Mikado; the teacher said that the supposed silliness of Japan was actually intended to poke fun back home at England. At the time I couldn't understand that idea ... now I can ...
